# Как запустить NodeJS проект в фоне на Linux сервере

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

Я запускаю через ssh сервер на nodejs но если я закрываю консольные окна то все отключается. как сделать что бы процессы работали в фоновом режиме.
Пробывал юзать screen но он тратит очень много памяти, нужно что то другое!

Comment: Linux-сервер находится на отдельной машине или на виртуальной? И каким именно образом вы запускаете сервер под Node?

Comment: находится на виртуальной машине , а запускаю командой yarn start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь пакетом `PM2` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

После запуска `pm2 start nameFile.js` создается демон - и консоль, из которой происходил запуск можно закрыть. Так же, `pm2` может самостоятельно создать файлы необходимой конфигурации для добавления в автозапуск сервера NodeJs (после перезагрузки ОС).
Для этого необходимо, после запуска сервера NodeJs, написать команду `pm2 startup`, а потом `pm2 save`.

Похожий пакет `nodemon` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon. Но я им не пользовался

Comment: а как запустить react проект через pm2 просто когда я запускаю api сервер я могу указать исполняемый файл server.js ,а с реактом так не получается. он запускается только командой yarn start

Comment: обычно, `yarn start` - это дев режим. На реальном сервере никто так проект не запускает. Нужно сделать билд проекта в прод. режиме и уже потом отталкиваться от этого. Возможно Вам и не нужен  NodeJs-сервер, а можно будет обойтись только Nginx

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вконец команды дописать символ

```
&
```

Comment: оно конечно работает но вместо 100 мегабайт оперативки начинает тратить 250 , для меня это критично

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/423560)

Comment: @Coder а на мой взгляд это вполне валидный ответ и самое правильное решение.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf  - см. комментарий ТС выше - это не решение заданного вопроса.

Comment: @Coder ТС выше как раз и сказал, что "оно конечно работает". Куда у него там 150 мб памяти улетает - никому не известно (да и не имеет отношения к вопросу).

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf как раз и с памятью вопрос - "Пробывал юзать screen но он тратит очень много памяти, нужно что то другое" и "начинает тратить 250 , для меня это критично".

Comment: @Coder любая вспомогательная программа, переводящая процесс в фоновый режим, будет потреблять какое-то количество памяти, но изначальный запуск процесса в фоне не потребляет памяти вообще. Если автор вопроса со мной не согласен, то не плохо было бы ему сначала определить, какой именно процесс съел его память.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf У нас уже обсуждение мнений, выходящее за рамки вопроса - ТС определился с подходящим ему решением - а насчет остального - работать может многое, костылей может быть много, решений тоже - в этом случае именно ТС определяет условия, в то числе с памятью и его мнение определяющим - в том числе и по памяти - его вопрос, его мнение. Имхо, конечно.

Comment: @Coder здесь я с вами согласен. Но то что ТС определился не означает что данный ответ совсем не содержит решения.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf, дело в том, что ТС в вопросе указал, что он запускает своим способом, но его не устраивает именно потребление памяти - именно это получается краеугольным камнем преткновения/проблемой. И в этом ответе именно это и является причиной неприятия. То есть - главный вопрос не в работе, как таковой, а в потреблении памяти, как мне думается - именно на вопросе памяти и заострен вопрос.